# Vue module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js)

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I google like 1 hour for this error and still found no fix.

Anyone have any idea why this happen and how can I fix it?

Here it is the full error message:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors  
 Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
 RangeError: Invalid string length
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `node_modules` dir and then run `npm install`?

Comment: Can you show the html template you are trying to load?

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1491

Comment: In the end, it looks like this happens due to a component error.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have vue-loader and vue-template-compiler in the dev dependencies in package.json file.

```
"devDependencies": {
    ....
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-loader": "^15.5.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
},
```

Comment: why should they be under devDependencies rather than just dependencies?